# is there a way to use numbers in a python array with strings

Tags: python, typeerror

I get this error from python when I try to run my program does anyone know how to fix it.

```
ops.append(i+".)"+names[i]+"'s Living Quarters\n")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

ops is a array for choices.

names is a array with names to be made in to the ops array with a number for printing.
i is a increasing number for the choice number.
sorry if there have been other questions like this, I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert your integer to a string before you can concatenate it. You can do this with `str(i)`.

Or you can accomplish your append line with f-strings, like so:

```py
ops.append(f"{i}.) {names[i]}'s Living Quarters\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ops.append(str(i)+".)"+str(names[i])+"'s Living Quarters\n")
```

Should work!
`str(VARIABLE)` converts the `VARIABLE` into `STR`(String)

Comment: Not quite sure the `str(names[i])` is necessary here though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integer in a string by either converting the integer to a string using
`str(variable)`, or by formatting it in the string using F-strings.

String formatting example:

```
stringName = f"Number: {integer_variable}"
```

Which can also be used for other variable types and is a bit more readable than concatenating a ton of variables to strings using `+`

Answer (score 0):

There's [lots of fun](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) ways to format strings in Python.  I tend to prefer `string.format` just because of the flexibility.

```
ops = "{}{}.) {}'s Living Quarters\n".format(ops, i, names[i])
```

Ideally, you'd include the formatting for ops in there as well, but since I didn't have the code you used to generate it , I just showed you the closest I could.